# JPA unique List of foreign Keys

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, playframework, unique-constraint

With Play 2.2. and EBean, I'd like to persist an object that has a List of other objects:

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Article> articles;
}

public class Article {
    public int id;
}
```

The table created by JPA that maps the relationship looks like this (in Postgres):

```
cart_id           | article_id
------------------+--------------
               61 |            3
               61 |            6
```

So in this example, the combination of article 3 and 6 can only exist once, in shopping cart 61. The combination of e.g. article 3 and 7 however is still *free*, but once inserted can also only exist once.

I would like every `ShoppingCart` to be unique, meaning that the List of `Article` can not be duplicate, so basically a unique constraint but on multiple foreign keys.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you really want.

If you want one shopping card list link to many article, you already have the solution.

In the present state, the article 3 and 6 can exist in many shopping cart

```
cart_id           | article_id
------------------+--------------
               61 |            3
               61 |            6
               62 |            3
               62 |            6
```

If what you want is that if one shopping cart is link to a set of article, no other shopping cart can have the same set of article, this can't be done by sql and column constraints only.
You'll have to create java/scala code to test if one set of articles has already been associated to a shopping cart.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the latter. Thanks for clarifying that this is not possible.